# FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraX-audio encoding thread

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I am recording videos using the camera X library. When i take video for 5 seconds before that (i,e)two seconds if i close the video its crashing with above error.How to handle this run time exception in android cameraX library

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraX-audio encoding thread
Process: .debug, PID: 4625
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_dequeueOutputBuffer(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2698)
    at androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture.audioEncode(VideoCapture.java:705)
    at androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture$1.run(VideoCapture.java:340)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

sometimes the below issue

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraX-video encoding thread
Process: <packagename>, PID: 10794
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(android.media.MediaCodec$BufferInfo, long)' on a null object reference
    at androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture.videoEncode(VideoCapture.java:604)
    at androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture$2.run(VideoCapture.java:348)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

in this samples also not fixed yet
https://github.com/android/camera-samples/issues/2#issuecomment-546812852

Answer (score 0):

By adding a callback to `videoCapture.startRecording(videoFile, executor, onVideoSavedCallback);` you should be able to handle the exeption in the `onError` method.

```
/**
 * Define callback that will be triggered after a video has been taken and saved to disk
 */
private VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedCallback onVideoSavedCallback= new VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedCallback() {
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public void onVideoSaved(@NonNull File file) {
        Log.d("VIDEO_CAPTURE", "Video capture succeeded");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int videoCaptureError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
        Log.e("VIDEO_CAPTURE", "Video capture failed");
        if (cause != null) {
            cause.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context,"Video capture failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Which version of cameraX are you using ?

Comment: implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.0-alpha06"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-alpha06"

Comment: I could handle this error on alpha07 with onVideoSavedCallback, I don´t know for alpha06. A lot of things changed between those versions, maybe you can try updating the library.

Comment: I checked in this GitHub link also but inbuilt exceptions not resolved

Comment: Is the exeption raising when you stop the video with stopRecording() or when you close the activity at 2 sec ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205532/discussion-between-laurentp22-and-ramesh-sambu).